# Having trouble installing SQLite

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

What I need is "System.Data.SQLite ADO.NET 4.0", which I cannot find in the home-page.

So I downloaded "Precompiled Binary (Windows) Zip Archive "  from [here](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html) (I think this is for .Net 3.5).

Now I am suppose to Copy SQLite.DLL to my project and add a reference.

But for some reason VS-2010 says "Cannnot be added . Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component."

I am reffering this  [site](http://www.mikeduncan.com/sqlite-on-dotnet-in-3-mins/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need an existing SQLite database. To help create your own SQLite databases outside of Visual Studio, use the [SQLite Admin](http://sqliteadmin.orbmu2k.de/) tool. It's very easy to use, and if you're 
familiar with SQL Server Management Studio and the like, you'll get it easy. Design your tables, etc, and you'll save it as a file (.s3db).

To give your application access to the SQLite database, download System.Data.SQLite at the [SourceForge page for SQLite ADO.NET Provider](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlite-dotnet2/). This will install the binaries into a directory like `C:\Program Files (x86)\SQLite.NET\bin\`. You can then reference these binaries from your .NET project. `System.Data.SQLite` and `System.Data.SQLite.Linq`.

This library is easy to use in your .NET project. This is an ADO.NET provider for a SQLite database. Basically it gives you the ability to use classes like `SQLiteConnection` and `SQLiteCommand`.

The original developer's site: http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/.

Comment: The binaries you mentioned ,will it run under .net framework 4 ?

Comment: Yes they will. They're compiled for .NET 2/3.5. I just created a sample assembly in .NET 4, referenced no problem. You won't need to downgrade your app or anything.

Comment: Should I replace the SQLite.DLL with latest version [from here](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html)

Comment: Yep; don't use SQLite.dll for programmatic access to your .s3db. That one is not a .NET managed assembly.

Comment: You mean I can't insert, update , delete data  from a vb.net app ?

Comment: Yes you can absolutely do that. The .dll that you mentioned from sqlite.org is not suitable for .NET development. Don't use it; get rid of it. You don't need it. Use the one from SourceForge. It's meant specifically for .NET development.

Comment: Ok I downloaded it again from the site , and for some reason now it works. I used this link to download : http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlite-dotnet2/files/SQLite%20for%20ADO.NET%202.0/1.0.66.0/